# I am trying to use webdriver in the selenium module but I keep getting an error no matter what I'm doing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

As stated, I am trying to use webdriver.Chrome in this sample project I'm doing but I am completely lost on what to do. This is the error I get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzVbE.png). But when I look at the version of chrome I installed, it seemed to match up. [Chrome Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VCp9.png). Does anyone know what's happening? Sorry if the post is too unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your chrome browser. Try to update the installed chrome version to latest version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But isn't my chrome version already updated to the one of the chromedriver?

Comment: Can you share screenshot of chrome version at here. Along with browser opening code?

Comment: Yes. The picture of the chrome version is hyperlinked in the post. And sorry I don't know what browser opening code is.... I'm a second year college student so I'm pretty clueless haha.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem, use WebDriverManager: refer - https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/ and https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager.

If you are using Python with selenium, refer to this post for sample code:

[Chrome with WebDriver--Why is it disappearing as soon as I hit "run"? Chrome Driver version 106 but Chrome can only be 105.0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861535/chrome-with-webdriver-why-is-it-disappearing-as-soon-as-i-hit-run-chrome-dri/73862379#73862379)

If you are using Java with selenium, refer to this post for sample code:

[element click intercepted in Selenium wedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807373/element-click-intercepted-in-selenium-wedriver/73808531#73808531)

Comment: Ok gotcha. That seemed to fix the errors. However, my chrome seems to reopen and close within brief moments. If I use time.sleep(), it seems to stay open for that duration and then close. Sorry if I'm asking too many questions or sound stupid, but is there a method I should use to fix this?

Comment: Try this code:    

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)